# Why Wordpress's wp-cron checks schedule only on each page load?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

In WordPress, I came across that wp-cron runs only on each page load and not as system cron which runs as per schedule even if no request comes. Can anyone explain this in detail? Also, is it true for all types of web servers?

Comment: This looks a *standard software* question: help me see the connection to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Because wp-cron and system crontab - is different systems. WP Cron save scheduled event in database with time and for every load wp site, wp cron check database and do event if it needed. System cron works with system time and run scripts.

For all sites normally use system crontab. For Wordpress you also can use crontab and disable wp-cron in wp-config.php

Comment: Why isn't this database checked continuously in the background and execute the cron task when it's scheduled? Why is a page load request needed to trigger that?